# How to use the results of one query to compose another query?

Tags: t-sql, dataexplorer

I am trying to query satckoverflow data at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow

```
SELECT Id as postId, PostTypeId, OwnerUserID, AcceptedAnswerId from posts 
where PostTypeId = 1
```

will give me a list of 50,000 questions and user Id of the user who posted the question (OwnerUserId) and the user Id of the person whose answer was accepted (AcceptedAnswerId).

Now I am trying to write a query to select a list of users who have either asked or posted the accepted answer.
Something like this:

```
Select Id, reputation from users 
INNER JOIN
(Select Id as postId, OwnerUserId, AcceptedAnswerId from posts)
ON
users.Id = posts.OwnerUserId or users.Id = posts.AcceptedAnswerId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is: you can do this with a `WITH` clause.

Trivial example:

```
WITH query1 AS
(SELECT * FROM myTable),
query2 AS
(SELECT * FROM query1)
SELECT * FROM query2;
```

`WITH` clauses greatly enhance readability of complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subselect for that.

```
SELECT u.Id, u.reputation, p.id as PostId, p.acceptedAnswerId
FROM users u
INNER JOIN posts p ON u.Id = p.OwnerUserId OR u.Id = p.AcceptedAnswerId
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
```

Though that takes a long time to run.  I'd add a constraint like `and p.LastEditDate > '01 Jan 2014'`

Answer (score 0):

For more complex scenarios you can create a temporary table/view like the one in [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194541/find-unanswered-questions-by-non-noob-within-last-week?MinRep=2000&NrDays=7) query.

You can create the table with `CREATE TABLE` and then `INSERT` the results of one query into it. Afterwards you are able to perform a standard `SELECT` on that table.